# How to find and hyperlink a URL in text(string), Java?

Tags: java, string, url, hyperlink

I have text including www.???????.com . I want to show it as clickable link make it italic or change its color in the text. is there way of determining and hyperlinking ?

Comment: To make your next question answerable, you'll want to give us the important and necessary details of the question. Good luck.

Comment: Regex might be what you want.

Comment: how much it could be detailed? question is simple. i m designing a lite powerpoint like gui for friend. and i want url in a text to be hyperlinked when i add textbox. and in Java not Javascript.

Comment: @user851032: you give absolutely no context whatsoever. Is this Swing? AWT? JSP? What? But again only give the necessary information if you want your post to be answerable.

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with making links clickable or changing appearance, wouldn't you really want JavaScript and not Java?  They're not the same thing - you know that, right?

Assuming that the answer is "yes, I meant JavaScript", you'll find these are easy things to do in jQuery.  it was invented to manipulate the DOM.

If the answer is "no", I'd recommend running JavaScript inside Java using Rhino:

http://weblog.raganwald.com/2007/07/javascript-on-jvm-in-fifteen-minutes.html

Comment: yah i know there is lots of ways with javascript but it is java unfortunately

Comment: Run JavaScript inside Java with Rhino, then.

Answer (score 0):

why not use CSS pseudo class for that http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp